# Why doesn't the instance variable take the new value

Tags: javascript, instance-variables, object-literal

Here is a code example:

```
var testObject =
{
   val1:  1,

   testing:  function( )
   {
      val1 = 2;
      alert( val1 );
   }
};
```

how come when alert prints val1, it's says undefined?

Comment: `val1` should be alerting `2`. Try creating a sample that reproduces the problem at http://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/qmLMV/

Note that `val1: 1` is a property, and the `val1 = 2;` inside the function body is a variable. Like with all variables, it will undergo identifier resolution. In this case, you are creating an implicit global variable which should be avoided. Declare your variables beforehand.

```
function() {
    var val1 = 2;
}
```

Also note this:

```
var testObject = {
   val1:  1,
   testing: function() {
      var val1 = 2;

      alert(val1); // alerts 2
      alert(this.val1); // alerts 1
   }
};
```

Use `this` to access the properties of the object from within that object's method.

Comment: @dave, hopefully you'll review the answer in full, as it points out that you are attempting to reference the `val1` property of `testObject` but instead you are referencing an implicit global `val1` variable. This can create all sorts of problems if you try later to access the property directly (it will always be set to `1`), and it may cause conflicts with other scripts if for whatever reason they expect to access an explicit global `val1` variable.